# Creating a graph with overlapping histograms and saving it to a single file

Tags: linux, matlab, histogram, saving-data

I am trying to write a Matlab script to analyze two specific sets of data, create histograms for them, and write them to a single file where you can see both histograms overlapped on one plot.

I created a functioning script that created the histogram for 1 set of data that basically went like this:

```
h1=figure;
hist(data,nbins:;

print(h1,'-dpng','hist.png)
```

Then I tried to simply add a second line of:

```
h2=figure;
```

and changed the print function to include h2. That obviously didn't work. I found that I couldn't have both an h1 and an h2 with the print function.

After searching the internet and looking for ways to get around this I decided to try to use saveas instead. I got to the following:

```
h=findobj(gca,'Type','patch');
hist(data1,nbins);
hold on;
hist(data2,nbins);

set(h(1),'FaceColor','r','EdgeColor','k');
set(h(2),'FaceColor','b','EdgeColor','k');

saveas(h,'-dpng','hist.png')
```

But this won't quite work either. I haven't found anything on the Mathworks website that helps me with this problem, and I haven't found anything on any other site either. I am using a Linux computer connecting to a different server via SSH so the only way that I can view plots that I make is by saving them to a file and then opening them. Please let me know if you have any suggestions to accomplish my task as outlined in my first paragraph. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use different axes for different histogram. You can use SUBPLOT for this:

```
subplot(2,1,1)
hist(data1,nbins);
subplot(2,1,2)
hist(data2,nbins);
```

Another way is to find a common bins (`x`) and return the `hist` output to vectors. Then use BAR function for the plot.

```
nbins = 20;
x = linspace(min([data1(:);data2(:)]),max([data1(:);data2(:)]),nbins);
h1 = hist(data1, x);
h2 = hist(data2, x);
hb = bar(x,[h1(:),h2(:)],'hist');

% change colors and set x limits
set(hb(1),'FaceColor','r','EdgeColor','k');
set(hb(2),'FaceColor','b','EdgeColor','k');
gap = x(2)-x(1);
xlim([x(1)-gap x(end)+gap])
```